# Is it possible to do an aws in place code deploy with zero downtime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, aws-code-deploy, amazon-elb

Is it possible to achieve zero downtime deployments with in place deployment? I know that in the in deployment group description (for in place deployment) we have this:

> Updates the instances in the deployment group with the latest application revision. During a deployment, each instance will be briefly taken offline for its update.

My question is: supposed I have at least two instances connected to a load balancer. Is it possible to do in place deployment using this sequence:

- instance A is disconnected from the LB (Load Balancer)
- instance A installs latest updates and restarts
- instance A is upgraded to latest code revision
- the LB disconnects from instance B which still has the old code revision, and points exclusively to instance A
- instance B installs latest revision and restarts
- instance B is upgraded to latest code revision
- the LB connects to instance B as well

Is the above possible? and if so how do i set it up? I've experimented with deploy one at a time, all at once etc but what happened is that in all cases the deployment always happened to all instances at the same time, and so there was some downtime.

Comment: Dear @abbood I currently have several customers with continuous deployments using cloudformation, auto scaling with rolling updates, and application load balancer without any issues. If you share more details about your current environment I might come up with something.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do exactly what you describe. If you configure your deployment group with the [deployment option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/APIReference/API_DeploymentStyle.html#CodeDeploy-Type-DeploymentStyle-deploymentOption) `WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL` and configure [a load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDeploymentGroup.html#CodeDeploy-CreateDeploymentGroup-request-loadBalancerInfo), CodeDeploy will remove your instances from the load balancer before it runs the usual set of Lifecycle hook scripts.

You can see a chart [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html#reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks-run-order) that demonstrates the order that the hooks are executed (note that `BlockTraffic` and `AllowTraffic` are performing the binding and unbinding). The host selection logic will be the same - your minimum healthy host settings. If you set your deployment to one at a time, CodeDeploy will not deploy to multiple instances at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think one option would be to create a revision for each deployment in a separate folder and eventually link it via symlink using afterInstall hook after deployment is complete.

eg.

```
 releases
    ├── release1
    └── release2

public_html -> (symlink) release2
```